# Specific Fibonacci Assignment in Python:

Tags: python, variable-assignment

Bit of preface, I understand there's a million and one Fibonacci questions but I've found nothing that can quite help me. My assignment is as such:

*Write a function fibonacci that receives a number as parameter and computes the fibonacci series up to that number. If the number passed is not an element of the fibonacci series, then the computation should stop at the immediate fibonacci number higher than the parameter passed. (e.g., if parameter passed is 100, which is not a fibonacci element, the iteration should stop at the next highest number of the fibonacci series 144). The function would return the list of fibonacci elements.*

I'm not asking for the solution (*but that certainly wouldn't be remiss!*) but a little advice would be helpful.

I'm familiar with the classic recursive method:

```
def calcFib(n):
   if n == 1:
      return (1)
   elif n == 0:
      return (0)
   else:
      return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

And I got it to 'work' with two methods that link together:

```
def callFib():
   mylist = []
   n = int(input("Enter number: "))
   while(n >= 0):
      mylist.append(calcFib(n))
      n = n - 1
      if(n==0):
          print (mylist)
```

But then I noticed that this actually calculates up the nth number in the series rather than it ending when the value is greater than the input. (*It's also very slow, but I believe I have to have this style of method for the question!*)

So any advice for a single method that can stick the whole Fibonacci Sequence into a list until the value is greater than the input?

Comment: So, this isn't really to do with fibonacci, rather exiting a loop at some condition. You could probably get rid of most of your question. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Hint: you should implement Fib in an iterative way (loop) instead of recursive. You can do the whole thing with one iteration instead of re-computing the same values over and over again.

Comment: You are using the "naive" exponential time fibonacci implementation, so yes, it's going to be very slow.

Answer (score 2):

First, use iteration:

```
old = 1
new = 1

while new < target:
   new, old = old+new, new
```

You give it the target value.  I think that's the whole program, now that I look at it ... except for input and output.

Answer (score 0):

Your Fibonacci function contains two recursive calls, which slows it down, and the function that calls it does so in a loop (calculating each number multiple times), slowing it down further.

An iterative Fibonacci solution is the first sample script displayed at https://www.python.org, so you can adapt that.

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    result = [0, 1]
    while a < n:
        result.append(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
    return result
```

You can call it like this:

```
>>> fib(13)
[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
>>> fib(12)
[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

13 is a Fibonacci number while 12 is not. Now you can simply print the last number in the list:

```
>>> fib(12)[-1]
13
```

And here is a better recursive method for the basic Fibonacci sequence:

```
def fib(n, a=0, b=1):
    return fib(n-1, b, a+b) if n else b
```

Adapted to work for this problem:

```
def fib(n, a=0, b=1):
    fib.result.append(a)
    return fib(n, b, a+b) if a<n else fib.result
```

Set `fib.result` first, then call fib:

```
>>> fib.result = []
>>> fib(13)
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
>>> fib.result = []
>>> fib(12)
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

The last number in the list is the answer:

```
>>> fib.result[-1]
13
```

Comment: This is great, really it was the:
`while a < n:
        result.append(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
    return result`
that was confusing me, seems rather more simple now, will have the spend a little time puzzling out the more efficient method but this is great.

Answer (score -2):

def calcFib(n):
if n == 1:
return (1)
elif n == 0:
return (0)
else:
return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

Comment: That does not look like correct python syntax. If you need help with that, please take the [tour] and follow the links you see there. And even if it were python, without any explanation it is unlikely to be perceived as helpful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).